# Cannot draw diagram

Tags: xy-pic

I'm trying to draw a diagram but I get the following error message:

`! Xy-pic error: in entry "1,1": No [ld] (is "2,0") from here.`

The code is:

```
\xymatrix{A\times B \ar[ld]_p \ar[rd]_q\\
          &A &B}
```

With the code

```
\xymatrix{& C \ar@/_/[ld]_f \ar[d]_{(f,g)} \ar@/^/[rd]^g\\
          & A\times B \ar[ld]_p \ar[rd]^q\\
          A && B}
```

here's the error I got:

`! Xy-pic error: in entry "1,2": No [rd] (is "2,3") from here.`

Comment: If you want a triangle, then add `&` before the first `A`; the second row should be `A && B`. In your code the first arrow wants to go left, but you're in the leftmost column, so the error. This should be thought of as a three column matrix.

Comment: Oh, I see. Why do I need two && on the second row?

Comment: I don't really understand the error messages from xypic. They are not really helpful for someone who has just started using the package.

Comment: If the bent arrows from C should point to A and B, there should be `[ldd]` and `[rdd]`: you want to go down *two* rows. Wouldn't it be better to add this to the other very similar question?

Comment: Oh, right, forgot that I actually have 3 rows as well. I'm not sure how to move this question to the previous one I posted. Feel free to move it if you want. Thanks egreg!

Comment: I've flagged it to the moderators who can take care of it.

Answer (score 8):

Let's see the triangle as a two row, three column matrix:

```
* & A \times B & * 

A &      *     & B
```

where `*` denotes an empty cell. Now it's easy to complete it with arrows:

```
\xymatrix{
  & A\times B \ar[ld]_{p} \ar[rd]^{q} \\
  A && B
}
```

You may want to reduce the distance between columns with something like

```
\xymatrix@C-6pt{
  & A\times B \ar[ld]_{p} \ar[rd]^{q} \\
  A && B
}
```

For the second diagram you have to go down by *two* rows from the "C" node:

```
\xymatrix{& C \ar@/_/[ldd]_f \ar[d]_{(f,g)} \ar@/^/[rdd]^g\\
          & A\times B \ar[ld]_p \ar[rd]^q\\
          A && B}
```