# Cannot draw commutative diagram

Tags: xy-pic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot draw diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60399/cannot-draw-diagram)

My code is:

```
\xymatrix{& C \ar@/_/[ld]_f \ar[d]_{(f,g)} \ar@/^/[rd]^g\\
          & A\times B \ar[ld]_p \ar[rd]^q\\
          A && B}
```

and the error I got:

```
! Xy-pic error: in entry "1,2": No [rd] (is "2,3") from here.
```